# How to grant ocrmypdf permission on docker?

Tags: docker

```
PS D:\> docker run --rm -i ocrmypdf "123.pdf" output.pdf
```

> InputFileError: File not found - 123.pdf

Docker cannot your working directory unless you explicitly share it with the Docker container and set up permissions correctly.
You may find it easier to use stdin/stdout:

```
docker run -i --rm jbarlow83/ocrmypdf - - <input.pdf >output.pdf
```

I searched on Google and it brought me to [this website](https://vsupalov.com/docker-shared-permissions/). However, I don't understand the instructions there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Seems you already found the answer: You either have to mount the file (or the entire directory) so docker can "see it" (`-v` switch in docker CLI), or read in from STDIN (the `<` syntax). So your second example should work, and if it doesn't work, you should describe the error here so people can help. See also  https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docker.html#using-the-docker-image-on-the-command-line. Note I'm not on Windows, so it could be that docker CLI behaves different on Windows when it comes to STDIN processing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.